# When should SSL_shutdown and SSL_free be called if there are errors?

Tags: openssl

In the official OpenSSL [TLS Server Example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server) there is

```
while(1) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    unsigned int len = sizeof(addr);
    SSL *ssl;
    const char reply[] = "test\n";

    int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
    if (client < 0) {
        perror("Unable to accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    } else {
        SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));
    }

    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    close(client);
}
```

This does not fully check for errors (for example, `ssl` may be null) and there are both `SSL_shutdown` and `SSL_free`.

`SSL_free` should be called when we want to release `ssl`, but when should `SSL_shutdown` be called? If there is an error in `SSL_set_fd` or `SSL_accept`, should it be shut down?

Answer (score 0):

From the SSL_shutdown [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_shutdown.html):

> Note that SSL_shutdown() must not be called if a previous fatal error
> has occurred on a connection i.e. if SSL_get_error() has returned
> SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL or SSL_ERROR_SSL.

Although I've personally never seen a problem calling this when there is a SSL error, so I think it would be safe anyway.

From the SSL_free documentation:

> SSL_free() decrements the reference count of ssl, and removes the SSL
> structure pointed to by ssl and frees up the allocated memory if the
> reference count has reached 0. If ssl is NULL nothing is done.

If you don't call this, you would be leaking memory.  So yes you do always need to call SSL_free when you are finished with the SSL pointer.

I use C++ [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) classes for all openssl handles so that the shutdown/free methods are always called.